# Redirect to a Site Page after Create New Document

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document

I am doing a createNewDocumentWithProgID via script within a webpart so a user can create a new doc based on a template.  What is lacking is once the new document is open and the user closes/saves the document and goes back to SP the SharePoint page is now at the Home Page.

Note the script is on a Page called New Docs.aspx.  How do I get the script to redirect to the NewDocs.aspx and not Home.aspx

Comment: Just curious if you are creating a custom "Create New Document"-solution only to include a template for a doc, 'cause that's something that can be done OOTB as well. Anyway, for the redirect: have a look at Event Receivers, e.g. https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/create-an-add-in-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-add-ins

Comment: I will suggest using "source" parameter - i.e. http://servername/site/Lists/MyList/EditForm.aspx?ID=1&Source=http://servername/site/default.aspx will redirect the user to the default.aspx page after editing the list item (clicking the OK\Save button).